# terragrunt before hook disable termporarily

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I would like to run terragrunt just for once without before hooks.
Looking at the documentation unable to find anything useful.
Also unable to find anything useful in the google search results.

Do we have a bash variable or command line options to achieve this?.

https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/hooks/#before-and-after-hooks

I am using terragrunt version v0.32.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
locals {
  hooks_enabled = get_env("DISABLE_HOOKS", "false") == "true" ? false : true
}

terraform {
  before_hook "some hook" {
    commands = local.hooks_enabled ? ["plan", "apply", "destroy"] : []
    execute = ["cmd", "args"]
  }
}
```

Running: `DISABLE_HOOKS=true terragrunt plan`